# How do i convert this 1471323637 into time

Tags: php, mysql, time

i'm currently looking at something and it says this.
"last_updated":1471323637

how can i convert that number into a time that I can actually read because at the moment i have no idea what time/date that is.

thank you.

Comment: that my friend is a [unix timestamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `FROM_UNIXTIME` if you want to convert it to human readable time in MySQL

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1471323637);
```

And you will get an output like below:

```
2016-08-16 11:00:37
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo date('H:i:s d/m/y' ,1471323637);
```

Output

```
10:30:37 16/08/16
```

for more info about date please read http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

You can also try this

```
echo date("g:i a, j M Y" ,1471323637);
```

Output

```
 10:30 am, 16 Aug 2016
```